# Help showing that a series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to show that the series: cos(k)/ln(k), where k goes from 2 to infinity, converges. I can understand that it does, but I have troubles showing it. Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Multiply with $2\cos(1/2)$ or with $2(1-\cos(1))$. Apply trigonometric identities, collect terms with the same angle and try to argue, in the first case, that $\frac1{\ln(k)}-\frac1{\ln(k+1)}$ behaves asymptotically like $\frac1{k\ln(k)^2}$.

Comment: Thank you @AnotherUser! I will make sure to write my next post in a better way, and also bring up what I have tried so far!

Answer (score 2):

Dirichlet's test will probably be of best use here. It states that if  $a_n$ decreases with
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=0$$
and the partial sum sequence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ is bounded, then the series $a_nb_n$ converges.

In this case,
$$a_k=\frac{1}{\ln(k)}$$
is clearly decreasing with $k$ (can be seen by definition) and approaches $0$.

Furthermore, if we look at $b_k=\cos(k)$, its sequence of partial sums is bounded (see [Lagrange's trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange%27s_trigonometric_identities)).

Therefore, by Dirichlet's test, we may conclude that the series $\frac{\cos(k)}{\ln(k)}=\frac{1}{\ln(k)}\cos(k)$ converges.